# How does damage scale with distance fired?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In TF2, when you fired weapons, there were three "ranges", long range, mid range, and close range.   Shooting enemies from long range resulted in extremely low damage (exception Sniper), mid range resulted in medium damage, and close quarters yielded the highest damage.

In CS:GO however, does damage scale with distance fired? In other words, if I fire a bullet at long range, compared to a bullet up close, will the two do completely different amounts of damage? Or is there no scale, and all bullets do the same damage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It scales linearly, and each gun has a different scaling factor known as its RangeModifier. Shotguns scale the worst, followed by SMG's and pistols, then automatics, then sniper rifles.

> Lowers damage based on the distance of a target. At 9.525m(500u) away, a target will receive an estimated damage of RangeModifier * Damage.

See the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuOy-5I1VcBMdGZmYndxUjctc1VNUDZHTXJFUE9Dbmc#gid=0) for more details.

Comment: Awe, so you can't headshot with a pump shotty from across the map, the way you could in CS:S and CS 1.6?

Comment: You can still do it, the damage just sucks. You just felt like you were doing a lot in 1.6 because of the "dink" sound from headshots.

Comment: I meant one-hit kill (from full HP) with a pump shotty from across the map, which you can sometimes do in those older games.